# What does code from openCV do?

Tags: c++, opencv

sample code of opencv 2.4.3 : find_obj_calonder.cpp has a line

```
 Mat img1 = imread( imgFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE ), img2, H12;
```

what does it means ? actually i want to know about the coma separated codes (i.e. img2, H12). how coma separated codes can be placed out side of function argument ?
sorry for my ignorance. enlighten me please...
thanks in advance...

Comment: It is just declaring three variables of type `Mat` : `img1`, `img2`, and `H12` and assigns a value to `img1` which happens to be the result of a function call.

Comment: ohh, i got it...thanks @Shafik Yaghmour

Comment: wheres my head today!!!...may be its exam sickness :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is simply declaring three variables of type `Mat`: `img1`, `img2` and `H12`. It is also assigning a value to `img1` which is the result of a function call:

```
imread( imgFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )
```

Answer (score 3):

`Mat img1 = imread( imgFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE ), img2, H12;`

Is the same as:

```
Mat img1 = imread( imgFilename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
Mat img2; 
Mat H12;
```

But it's horrible style - don't do this!